# Is there a Ruby dealloc method?

Tags: ruby

Is there a dealloc method for Ruby?

I have a class that makes DB connections. I would like to disconnect the connection whenever the class gets dealloced. It's just good cleanup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby is a language with GC, so no, there's no dealloc. (You *could* hook into finalizer, but that is really not the place to do cleanup)

Instead of each instance having its own connection (and need to clean up), I recommend using connection pool approach. You'll have fewer connections, concentrated in one place. Easier to manage.